# Unificar la reputación de Stack Overflow en español con la de Stack Overflow (en inglés)

Tags: discusión, reputación

Creo que el objetivo de la red Stack Exchange es medir el conocimiento de los usuarios en cada una de las comunidades, lo cual es muy muy bueno, y la forma que lo gestionan es muy muy buena.

Ahora bien, creo que no debería haber diferencia entre Stack Overflow en inglés y en español, ya que la única diferencia entre estas dos comunidades es el idioma, no el conocimiento.

Creo que la actividad de un usuario debería aportar a la reputación de ambos sitios. No pongamos más barreras de las que ya existen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El objetivo de las comunidades de Stack Exchange no es el de medir conocimiento. Es el de tener preguntas y respuestas de calidad para así dar solución a problemas o proporcionar conocimientos.

La diferencia entre SO y SOes (así como con SOru, SOpt y SOjp) no es solo el idioma.
Tienen el mismo nombre, tienen una *misma* temática pero cada comunidad elige como quiere que sea el sitio.
Eso hace que cada sitio sea distinto.

Para una agrupación de la reputación, puedes ver tu perfil de Red, en vez de cada sitio individualmente. Y verás como todas tus medallas y tu reputación forman una cantidad global entre todas tus cuentas (que tengan más de 200 rep si no me equivoco).

Y por cierto, ¿a qué barreras te refieres?

Comment: Agrego que también está la [bonificación de asociación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Si es un usuario que sabe manejarse en un sitio de SE (con 200+), empieza en cualquier sitio con 101. (Si es que se refería a esas barreras).

Comment: Me referia a la barrera del idioma, pero parece que la pregunta fue mal interpretada pq ya veo q ha sido botada (-8), olvídalo solo trataba que SO fuera un mejor sitio, en ningun momento lo hice con una mala crítica. :)

Comment: @JaimeRoman no necesariamente malinterpretada. Yo personalmente voté negativo porque no veo que esto sea algo viable ni necesario, ergo una*mala pregunta de meta*. Es bueno que quieras mejorar el sitio pero para eso hay muchas otras acciones que están de nuestra mano. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, quisiera eliminar la pregunta ya que realmente no es de importancia pero no me deja el sitio pq otros usuarios han respondido, pero es que realmente no tiene sentido que siga aquí la pregunta

Comment: @JaimeRoman tampoco es necesario borrarla. Imagina que alguien pueda tener la misma duda que tú, tendría aquí una publicación de referencia.